# Safari IOS 7 seems to start ASP.NET Session for every page

Tags: asp.net, safari, ios7

We have an ASP.NET 4.0  site which redirects to a mobile version on Session_Start in global.ascx .

The mobile site also has a link to redirect to full desktop site - but in Safari on IOS 7, this link always goes back to the mobile site.

Its as if the Session_Start in global.ascx is always firing when displaying a page in Safari IOS 7 (rather than just doing the detection once per session).

Chrome works OK on IOS 7 as does browsers in Android.

Just wondering if anyone else has observed this behaviour.

Answer (score 4):

If your site is running in standalone mode, i.e. has the tag

```
<meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
```

and you launch the web app from an icon on the home screen, Safari does not pass cookies back and forth to the server.  Since your session state is maintained with a cookie, it gets lost.

Not sure if Apple considers this a 'feature' or a 'bug' but it is breaking a LOT of web apps.